# CUDA programming in parallel

Tags: c++, cuda

So I've gone over this multiple times and just cant seem to figure it out. What is happening is my variable that I am trying to copy from GPU memory to CPU memory always appears to be blank.

From my understanding, I should have a variable or multiple variables and create copies of these which I will send to the GPU along with some data to compute, once it is done computing, come back and insert the contents of the variable from GPU into the one from CPU.

But every time I do this, my variable 'd_result' is always empty. If anyone has an idea on how to fix this, it would be much appreciated.

My CUDA function:

```
__global__ void gpu_histogram_equalization(unsigned char * img_out, unsigned char * img_in,
                            int * hist_in, int img_size, int nbr_bin){

    int *lut = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*nbr_bin);
    int i, cdf, min, d;
    /* Construct the LUT by calculating the CDF */
    cdf = 0;
    min = 0;
    i = threadIdx.x;
    while(min == 0){
        min = hist_in[i++];
    }
    d = img_size - min;
    if(i < nbr_bin){
        cdf += hist_in[i];
        //lut[i] = (cdf - min)*(nbr_bin - 1)/d;
        lut[i] = (int)(((float)cdf - min)*255/d + 0.5);
        if(lut[i] < 0){
            lut[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Get the result image */
    if(i < img_size){
        if(lut[img_in[i]] > 255){
            img_out[i] = 255;
        }
        else{
            img_out[i] = (unsigned char)lut[img_in[i]];
        }

    }
}
```

And then my function which calls it:

```
PGM_IMG gpu_contrast_enhancement_g(PGM_IMG img_in)
{
    PGM_IMG result;
    int hist[256];
    unsigned char * d_result;

    result.w = img_in.w;
    result.h = img_in.h;
    result.img = (unsigned char *)malloc(result.w * result.h * sizeof(unsigned char));

    cudaMalloc(&d_result, result.w * result.h * sizeof(unsigned char));

    cudaMemcpy(d_result, result.img, result.w * result.h * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    histogram(hist, img_in.img, img_in.h * img_in.w, 256);
    gpu_histogram_equalization<<<1,result.w * result.h * sizeof(unsigned char)>>>(d_result,img_in.img,hist,result.w*result.h, 256);

    cudaMemcpy(result.img, d_result, result.w * result.h * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you want help with debugging, you are going to have to provide the shortest, complete example which someone else could compile and run, because the code you have provided is not sufficient. Also, every CUDA API call returns a status, you should be checking them all for runtime errors. What happens if you run your code with cuda-memcheck? Does it report any problems?

Comment: Also, could you please edit your question title to make it describe your problem. Titles are important for search, and your title says absolutely *nothing* about what your question actually is

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this line:

```
gpu_histogram_equalization<<<1,result.w*result.h*sizeof(unsigned char)>>>
        (d_result,img_in.img,hist,result.w*result.h, 256);
```

Here are some issues you have:

1. img_in.img - This is host memory
2. hist - This is host memory

What is happening is that your kernel crashes due to invalid memory access.

Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) about error checking.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the kernel arguments in that code you have quoted, you can see that for any non trivial image size, the block dimensions will be  so large as to mean the kernel never even launches.